# how to insert two columns in latex?

Tags: columns

I wish to write the code of the picture displayed below..

How do I code this? I am confused[image]

Comment: Googling 'latex two columns' returns [texblog: Creating two columns in article, report or book](http://texblog.org/2007/08/11/creating-two-columns-in-article-report-or-book/) as the second result, and [LaTeX Wikibook: Page Layout](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout) as the third.

Comment: There are many options: The simplest would be to use a `tabular` environment with two columns: `\begin{tabular}{ll} [. . .] \end{tabular}` If you need text wrapping in the right column you can write `\begin{tabular}{l p{0.5\linewidth}` for example.

Comment: If you can show us a complete sample document with the code you've tried, we can help you better.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make two columns in two columns](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107269/how-can-i-make-two-columns-in-two-columns)

Comment: Downvoter: I think the comments were sufficient without the downvote. We have all had times when we didn't know where to start.

Comment: @Zay Good, I will convert my comment to an answer, then.

Comment: yesh please do..@AndrewCashner... also thanks for being nice..

Comment: more options including `multicol` and `minipages` at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491717/how-to-display-a-content-in-two-column-layout-in-latex

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One simple way to put a short portion of text into two columns, if the rows need to line up, is to use the basic `tabular` environment. You can use the `p` specification to get a row with wrapped text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l p{0.5\linewidth}}
Line 1 on the left  & Line 1 on the right\\
Line 2 on the left  & Line 2 on the right overflowing with a lot of extra text\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

For beginners in TeX who find this answer helpful, you can find a basic introduction to LaTeX by entering `texdoc lshort` at a terminal.

Comment: Is there a way to allow spaces to align the columns in the source document without getting overfull hbox errors?

Comment: @AndrewHundt Yes, TeX ignores most extra whitespace so you can insert spaces or tabs between columns to align the source code. Overfull hboxes happen when there is too much text in a table cell to fit in the box allotted to it, among other reasons.

Answer (score 3):

As seen on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491717/how-to-display-a-content-in-two-column-layout-in-latex there are multiple useful options:

#### Multicol

Use the [multicol](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package (if you omit the `\columnbreak`, the columns will balance automatically):

```
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{multicols}{2}
Column 1
\columnbreak
Column 2
\end{multicols}
```

#### Minipages

Alternatively, for precise control, add a minipage:

```
\begin{minipage}[position]{width}
text
\end{minipage}
```

You may also find this useful: [How do I force a column-break in a multi-column page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8683/how-do-i-force-a-column-break-in-a-multi-column-page)