# How to get horizontal parts of an exercise?

Tags: math-mode, enumerate, exercises, teaching

My question is how may I specify that the parts to a question be typeset horizontally with the option to specify the amount of rows as well as shown below. It is also essential that the level of enumeration inside the exercises start with lowercase letters (not numbers).

[image]

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That seems to do the trick, however the part regarding the enumeration style being lower-case alphabetical is not there yet. Thank you though!

Comment: That's left as an exercise to you ;-)

Comment: `multicols` and `enumerate` will enumerate in columns rather than in rows like in the picture. But there are a number of questions here asking the same thing: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107269/, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149273/

Comment: @clemens: Thanks for providing `tasks` ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer :)

Comment: @clemens: I thought of `tasks` already, but wrote too quickly that undesirable feature of `multicols` and `enumerate` with somewhat 'transposed' counting.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I already guessed that (seeing your answer) :)

Comment: Is there a way I can keep using multicols and enumerate? Maybe at least someone can point me out in the right direction?

Comment: @1028: The problem with `multicols` and `enumerate` is that `enumerate`  traverses downwards along the column, not horizontally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `tasks` package by your fellow user *clemens*.

To get three 3 columns, say

```
\begin{tasks}(3) 
\task ... 
\task etc. 
\end{tasks}
```

The task labels can be changed with `counter-format={(tsk[a])}`, where 'tsk' will be replaced with the actual task counter. `[a]` will use `\alph`, i.e. lower case characters. (See the `tasks` manual for more options)

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Evaluate each expression without calculator
\settasks{counter-format={(tsk[a])},label-offset=1em}
\begin{tasks}(3)
  \task $(-3)^4$ 
  \task $-3^4$
  \task $3^{-4}$
  \task $\dfrac{5^{23}}{5^{21}}$
  \task $\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^{-2}$
  \task $16^{-3/4}$
\end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems like a good way to do it! I keep getting that tasks is deprecated option in my build log. What is that about?

Comment: @1028: I don't understand. `tasks` is a rather new package by clemens, I don't think it's deprecated

Comment: I don't understand either, it keeps asking me for epic.sty and I don't know what package that's from.

Comment: @1028: Yes, `tasks` requires the `epic` package, but I don't have this warning. Have you updated your distribution?

Comment: I believe so, I'm running Arch and under tasks it says it is installed and up to date. I am however using TeXLive so if you're referring to the package here: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/epic?lang=en  then it is not contained in TeXLive.

Comment: I am using TeXLive 2015, daily updated

Comment: I will recheck then! Thank you for replying! I appreciate it!

Comment: @1028 can you look in the log file what the warning says *exactly*? (There's nothing deprecated about `tasks`… so I'm wondering what this might be?)

Comment: @clemens Here is my log file:  ! LaTeX Error: File `epic.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tasks/tasks.sty:56: Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.56 \msg_new:nnn
                  {tasks} {deprecated-option} 
No pages of output.
Transcript written on /tmp/gummi_TDO63X.log.

Comment: @1028: `epic` is on TeXLive, I've completely installed yesterday on my new machine, from scratch, and fetched no other packages so far -- it's on my new machine, so I could only get from TL. The error message is perhaps misleading here.

Comment: @1028 Ah, so the deprecated thing is secondary and the error really is ` ! LaTeX Error: File `epic.sty' not found.`, thanks.

Comment: So I would assume that my problem is epic.sty?

Comment: @1028: Yes, install the `eepic` bundle (note `eepic`, not `epic`)

Comment: Ohhhh, that changes everything...

Comment: Compilation successful! Thank you ChristianHupfer and @clemens !